GPU out of memory using hugging face
Pytorch is throwing GPU out of memory error
this is the code
from diffusers import StableDiffusionControlNetPipeline, ControlNetModel, UniPCMultistepScheduler
from diffusers.utils import load_image
import cv2
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
import torch
import urllib.request
import requests
import json
import os
from django.core.cache import cache
import uuid




class GenerateImages():

    def __init__(self):            
            self.device = 'cuda:0'
            self.controlnet = ControlNetModel.from_pretrained("lllyasviel/sd-controlnet-canny", torch_dtype=torch.float16).to(self.device)
            self.pipe = StableDiffusionControlNetPipeline.from_pretrained("runwayml/stable-diffusion-v1-5", 
            controlnet=self.controlnet, torch_dtype=torch.float16, use_safetensors=True).to(self.device)
            self.pipe.scheduler = UniPCMultistepScheduler.from_config(self.pipe.scheduler.config)
            self.pipe.enable_model_cpu_offload()
            self.pipe.enable_xformers_memory_efficient_attention()




    def generate_images(self, canny_image,org_image_path, prompt,image_count, user_folder='generated'):
        org_image=Image.open(org_image_path)
        output_list = []
        if(torch.cuda.is_available()):
            generator = torch.Generator(device=self.device).manual_seed(0)
        else:
            generator = torch.Generator().manual_seed(0)
        prompt = [prompt]
        output = self.pipe(
            prompt,
            canny_image,
            negative_prompt=['monochrome, lowres, bad anatomy,unrealistic,composite , worst quality, low quality'],
            generator=generator,
            num_inference_steps=20,
            num_images_per_prompt=image_count,
        ).images
        image_list = []
        for x in output:
            temp_image = x
            temp_image.paste(org_image, (0, 0), org_image)
            image_list.append(temp_image)
        processed_folder = os.path.join('media', user_folder)
        if not os.path.exists(processed_folder):
            os.makedirs(processed_folder, exist_ok=True)
        processed_images = image_list
        processed_image_paths=[]
        for i, processed_image in enumerate(processed_images):
            unique_filename = str(uuid.uuid4())
            processed_image_path = os.path.join(processed_folder, f'processed_image_{unique_filename}_{i + 1}.png')
            processed_image.save(processed_image_path)
            processed_image_paths.append(processed_image_path)

        torch.cuda.empty_cache()
        print(image_list,processed_image_paths)
        return image_list,processed_image_paths

error message : if image count is greated then one
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1532, in _wrapped_call_impl
 return self._call_impl(*args, **kwargs)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1541, in _call_impl
return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/accelerate/hooks.py", line 166, in new_forward
output = module._old_forward(*args, **kwargs)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/diffusers/models/controlnet.py", line 797, in forward
 controlnet_cond = self.controlnet_cond_embedding(controlnet_cond)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1532, in _wrapped_call_impl
return self._call_impl(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1541, in _call_impl
return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/diffusers/models/controlnet.py", line 100, in forward
 embedding = F.silu(embedding)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/nn/functional.py", line 2102, in silu
 return torch._C._nn.silu(input)
torch.cuda.OutOfMemoryError: CUDA out of memory. Tried to allocate 1.43 GiB. GPU

trying to generate images

how much memory does your gpu have?

hold on, this looks like your trying to turn this into a web service. Is it creating a model on each request? That'll fill your gpu up quickly.

i have a 16 gb gpu, yes , i am trying to make a web service  i don't think it is creating a model in each request
